# What does an op-amp amplify?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier

What does an operational amplifier (op-amp) amplify? Is it power, voltage or current?

Comment: Did you read the wiki for an Op-Amp?

Comment: You really need to do more research on your own, why do you need a special explanation **just for you** ? This basic question can be answered by reading a book about opamps. Search on google for "Opamps for everyone" to learn more.

Comment: @Tyler I didn't read it all but I scanned it to find an answer but didn't find

Comment: @MedNait The answer to your question is in the first 1/2 of a sentence.

Comment: @Tyler I read the first paragraph, it sure says that opamp amplifies voltage, but I wanted more info about the aspects of current and power amplification

Comment: It amplifies operational, weren't you listening? /s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically opamps are voltage amplifiers.  The output voltage is the difference between the two input signals times a large gain.

This raw capability can be used in circuits to ultimately amplify various parameters, including power and current.

Note that opamp inputs are high impedance, and the opamp output can source or sink a lot more current than the inputs take.  This means a opamp is also a power amplifier, even if it didn't amplify voltage.

In practise, this is mostly pointless symantics since opamps of of little use as amplifiers by themselves.  In most useful amplifier circuits, opamps are used with feedback around them and other circuitry to amplify particular parameters.  These usually include voltage gain, but much less than the bare opamp has, and significant impedance reduction, hence also current and power gain even with unity voltage gain.

Comment: Great answer! So basically they amplify voltage but can also amplify current or power, an example would be the voltage follower I suppose.

Comment: Is it possible to find a circuit (based on opamp) that amplifies only current, keeping power fixed, let's say by reducing voltage?

Comment: @Med: It's hard to only amplify voltage or current.  You can only pick one parameter to control, and the load decides the other degree of freedom.  A voltage follower is a good example.  The voltage gain is controlled to be 1.  The actual current can be much higher than the input current, but that depends on what the load draws.  If left open circuit, for example, then there is no current amplification going on since the output current is 0.

Comment: Great! You gave me the insights I wanted, a thousand thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

It amplifies voltage, the voltage difference between two pins called the inverting and non-inverting inputs. It outputs a voltage but that voltage is sourced from a circuit that can deliver a reasonable amount of current so immediately you can start to think that the very tiny amounts of current that the op-amp inputs might need (bipolar input op-amps) get turned into several mA at the output when the output connects to a load resistor. This makes it a current amplifier.

Then it's simply a case of realizing that this makes an op-amp an amplifier of power.

Comment: Great, this confirms the answer of Olin Lathrop and makes you think about the output too, cool.